# How do I make my JavaScript prompt redirect to a different page if the person doesn't qualify

Tags: javascript

```
var age = prompt("How old are you??")

if(age < 18)
{

}
else
{

}
```

I was just wondering how I make this JavaScript code either redirect to a different page or allow the user to continue on the page they clicked, if of aged.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This seems to be the same question as [How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(age < 18) {
    window.location.href = 'not-old-enough.html';
} else {
    // Do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (age < 18) {
    window.location.href = 'not-old-enough.html';
} else {
    return false;
}
```